# Parsing XML with TagSoup : bug with long attributes?

Tags: java, android, tag-soup

I'm trying to parse ugly HTML with TagSoup to extract value of a given tag.
Here is the tag :

```
<input type="hidden" name="hash_check" value="ffc39410ed8da309408a9382450ddc85" />
```

I want to retrieve value of attribute "value" ("ffc39410ed8da309408a9382450ddc85")

And here is my code, in my SAX handler :

```
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException
{
    if (localName.equals("input"))
    {
        Log.v(TAG, Integer.toString(atts.getLength()));
        if (atts.getValue("name").equals("hash_check")
        {
            in_input = true;
            Log.v(TAG, atts.getValue("name"));
            if (atts.getValue("value") != null)
                Log.v(TAG,atts.getValue("value");
        }
    }
}
```

Logs are here for debugging purposes. Logcat correctly gives me "hash_check" for atts.getValue("name"), but an empty string for atts.getValue("value") although the parser is positionned to the right "input" (the one and only of my html document).

What's wrong ? Bug in TagSoup ?

Thanks

edit @bkail : thank you for your comment. Here are more details and code.

First, the URL that I'm trying to parse : http://forum.hardware.fr/hfr/Programmation/Divers-6/experts-puissant-internet-sujet_37483_1.htm

And the code used to instanciate the parser :

```
private static final String FORUM_URI = "http://forum.hardware.fr/hfr/Programmation/Divers-6/experts-puissant-internet-sujet_37483_1.htm";
URL hfrUrl = new URL(FORUM_URI);
Parser parser = new Parser();
HfrSAXHandler sh = new HfrSAXHandler();
parser.setContentHandler(sh);
parser.parse(new InputSource(hfrUrl.openStream()));
```

And finally, the whole code for my SAX parser :

```
public class HfrSAXHandler extends DefaultHandler
{
    private boolean in_input = false;
    private static final String TAG = "hfr4droid";

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "start of parsing");
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException
    {
        if (localName.equals("input"))
        {
            Log.v(TAG, Integer.toString(atts.getLength()));
            if (atts.getValue("name") != null)
            {
                in_input = true;
                Log.v(TAG, atts.getValue("name"));
                if (atts.getValue("value") != null)
                    Log.v(TAG, Integer.toString(atts.getValue("value")));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException
    {
        if (localName.equals("input"))
            in_input = false;
    }
}
```

Thanks for giving it a try.

Comment: After fixing the parse errors, it works for me using tagsoup-1.2 on Java 6 on my laptop.  More details?  Sample code?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've edited my post to give you more details.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Integer.toString()` is the problem. Change this:

```
Log.v(TAG, Integer.toString(atts.getValue("value")));
```

to this:

```
Log.v(TAG, atts.getValue("value") );
```